# Unknown error "Unresolved reference" for List<E>.addAll method in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I have the following data class in Kotlin.

```
data class UserAccount(
    val accountName:  String,
    val accountLink:  String,
    val accountPhoto: String
)
```

I also have the following code that is giving me a headache.

```
var x: List<UserAccount> = emptyList()
var y: List<UserAccount> = emptyList()

x.addAll(y)
```

Could anyone shed some light on what exactly I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to use a `MutableList` instead? `List` does not have an `addAll` method.

Comment: @Sweeper Oh yes, silly me. I would be happy to accept this answer.